# convert from http to https of url Image from json,

Tags: json, image, http, https

I'm using an api where i receive a json as the response. One of the json fields is an image, the problem that i'm having is that i want that image to be in a https url, currently the image url is an http url and my website is showing me that images are insecure.
Can i make something to convert that url from http to https or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just call .replace() on the resultant string.  Something like this:

```js
let str = response.image_url;

let url = str.replace('http', 'https');

console.log(url);
```